# Enable overflow settings menu on the device soft keys?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I'm really not sure what to call it exactly. How do you enable the overflow settings menu in the navigation on screen keys

Below is what i want to achieve. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the **Action Overflow Button**. It is not recommended to enable this button.

This article explains why, and how to put it there if you still want to.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html